# How to write an aggregate query to figure the count in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have the following JSON context and I have a requirement to aggregate the distinct keywords under `conversion_token` group and the count it is repeated; for instance:

```
"conversion_token": [
                    {
                        "keyword": "DBMS",
                        "count":4,
                        "classify":2
                            }
```

the keyword DBMS is used multiple times under different constructs in the json provided, the aggregate should display the

```
"conversion_token": [
                    {
                        "keyword": "DBMS",
                        "count":6,
                        "classify":2
                            }
                {
                        "keyword": "NVL",
                        "count":2,`enter code here`
                        "classify":2
                            }
```

etc..

How can I do this?

```
{
    "select_emp": {
        "specification": {
            "input": [
                "p_empno"
            ],
            "declare_stmt": {
                "anchorvariable": [
                    "V_ENAME",
                    "V_HIREDATE",
                    "V_TITLE",
                    "V_REPORTSTO",
                    "V_DISP_DATE",
                    "V_INS_COUNT",
                    "CITY_FROM"
                ],
                "tablename_variable": [
                    "EMPLOYEE.V_ENAME",
                    "EMPLOYEE.V_HIREDATE",
                    "EMPLOYEE.V_TITLE",
                    "EMPLOYEE.V_REPORTSTO",
                    "EMPLOYEE.V_DISP_DATE",
                    "EMPLOYEE.V_INS_COUNT",
                    "EMPLOYEE.CITY_FROM"
                ]
            }
        },
        "body": {
            "select_stmt1": {
                "columns": [
                    "FIRSNAME",
                    "HIREDATE",
                    "TITLE",
                    "REPORTSTO"
                ],
                "tablename": [
                    "EMPLOYEE"
                ],
                "conversion_token": [
                    {
                        "keyword": "NVL",
                        "count": 1,
                        "classify": 2
                    }
                ]
            },
            "select_stmt2": {
                "columns": [
                    "CITY"
                ],
                "tablename": [
                    "EMPLOYEE"
                ],
                "conversion_token": [
                    {
                        "keyword": "DECODE",
                        "count": 1,
                        "classify": 3
                    }
                ]
            },
            "dbms_stmt1": {
                "dbms_putline": [
                    "P_EMPNO",
                    "V_ENAME",
                    "V_DISP_DATE",
                    "V_REPORTSTO"
                ],
                "conversion_token": [
                    {
                        "keyword": "DBMS",
                        "count": 1,
                        "classify": 2
                    }
                ]
            },
            "forloop1": {
                "select_stmt": {
                    "columns": [
                        "EMPLOYEEID",
                        "ROWID"
                    ],
                    "tablename": [
                        "EMPLOYEE"
                    ],
                    "conversion_token": [
                        {
                            "keyword": "DBMS",
                            "count": 1,
                            "classify": 2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "merge_stmt1": {
                "merge_into": "EMPLOYEE",
                "merge_using": {
                    "columns": [
                        "EMPLOYEEID",
                        "LASTNAME",
                        "TITLE",
                        "BIRTHDATE",
                        "HIREDATE",
                        "ADDRESS",
                        "CITY",
                        "STATE",
                        "COUNTRY",
                        "POSTALCODE",
                        "PHONE",
                        "FAX",
                        "EMAIL",
                        "BONUS"
                    ],
                    "tablename": [
                        "EMPLOYEE"
                    ]
                },
                "merge_update": {
                    "columns": [
                        "BONUS"
                    ],
                    "tablename": [
                        "EMPLOYEE"
                    ]
                },
                "merge_delete": {
                    "columns": [
                        "BONUS"
                    ],
                    "tablename": [
                        "EMPLOYEE"
                    ]
                },
                "merge_insert": {
                    "columns": [
                        "EMPLOYEEID",
                        "LASTNAME",
                        "FIRSTNAME",
                        "TITLE",
                        "BIRTHDATE",
                        "HIREDATE",
                        "ADDRESS",
                        "CITY",
                        "STATE",
                        "COUNTRY",
                        "POSTALCODE",
                        "PHONE",
                        "FAX",
                        "EMAIL",
                        "BONUS"
                    ],
                    "tablename": [
                        "EMPLOYEE"
                    ]
                },
                "conversion_token": [
                    {
                        "keyword": "Merge",
                        "count": 1,
                        "classify": 4
                    }
                ]
            },
            "exception_handling1": {
                "dbms_putline": [
                    "P_EMPNO"
                ],
                "conversion_token": [
                    {
                        "keyword": "DBMS",
                        "count": 1,
                        "classify": 2
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to concat `conversion_token` arrays into one using `project` and `$concatArrays`. Then using `$unwind`, you can separate each `conversion_token` object to make them ready for aggregation. After `$unwind`, you can group them by `keyword` using `$group` and you can take sum of `count`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        conversion_tokens: {
            $concatArrays:
                [
                    "$select_emp.body.select_stmt1.conversion_token",
                    "$select_emp.body.select_stmt2.conversion_token",
                    "$select_emp.body.dbms_stmt1.conversion_token",
                    "$select_emp.body.forloop1.conversion_token",
                    "$select_emp.body.merge_stmt1.conversion_token",
                    "$select_emp.body.exception_handling1.conversion_token"
                ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$conversion_tokens"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$conversion_tokens.keyword",
        count: {
            $sum: "$conversion_tokens.count"
        }
    }
}
])
```

This will produce an array like:

```
{
  "_id": "DBMS",
  "count": 3
}, {
  "_id": "NVL",
  "count": 1
}, {
  "_id": "DECODE",
  "count": 1
}
```

If you want to change the `_id` key with `keyword`, you can use `$project` again.